# Getting System Up-time

Tags: c++, c, windows

I'm having trouble to determine how long system is running. I'm just too tired for now, but have nothing to do. I used GetTickCount() to get Milliseconds, but I have to convert them human readable format. I tried something like this but I get strange results.

```
void GetUpTime(DWORD Tick) //GetTickCount() argument.
{
    wchar_t temp[256] = {0};
    ZeroMemory(tmpBuff, sizeof(tmpBuff));

    wsprintfW(temp, L"%uh %um %us", Tick/60, Tick/60*60, Tick/60*60*60);
    lstrcpyW(Time, tmpBuff);
}
```

as I guess here, Tick/60 = seconds, Tick/60*60 = minutes and Tick/60*60*60 = hours. but I need something like: 1h 5m 36s not the whole conversation.
Regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Tick/60*60` means the same thing as `(Tick/60)*60`, which is clearly not what you want.  You likely meant `Tick/(60*60)` instead.

---

You can "peel off" each unit if you want something more readable:

```
DWORD seconds = Tick / 1000;  /* Milliseconds -> seconds */
DWORD minutes = seconds / 60; /* Seconds -> minutes */
DWORD hours = minutes / 60;   /* Minutes -> hours */

/* Adjust seconds and minutes to leave only the remainder. */
seconds %= 60;
minutes %= 60;

wsprintfW(temp, L"%uh %um %us", hours, minutes, seconds);
```

Comment: oh yes, sorry. but I still need format like that. I'm getting insane values :( 6541159h 109019m 1816s
1816 seconds doesn't exist, it must be added to minutes and so on.

Comment: @OvérFlôwz You didn't convert from milliseconds to seconds, for one thing.  See my updated answer.

Comment: oh, thank you! I figured out how to do it now :) is my example correct too?
 Hours = Tick/(60*60*60);
 Minutes = Tick/(60*60);
 Seconds = Tick/60;

 while(Seconds > 59)
 {
  Seconds -= 60;
  Minutes += 1;
 }

 while(Minutes > 59)
 {
  Minutes -= 60;
  Hours += 1;
 }

Comment: @OvérFlôwz That's one way to do it, but then you will have to run one loop iteration for each hour + minute the system has been up. Using mathematical operators (my approach) the code will run in constant time; in yours it will run in roughly linear time with respect to the current hour/minute on the clock.

Comment: Thank you, fill fix it asap!

Comment: I meant minute + second, not hour + minute.  In the worst case, you will run 118 iterations (59 of each loop) and 120 comparisons.  That's not terrible, but why waste those cycles? :)

Comment: You're right, fixed already. Thanks for help :) Will accept answer after 2 minutes, I can't now.