# Display time string given system tick count

Tags: c, timestamp

Given:

- number of system ticks since cold start via `unsigned int systemTicks(void);`
- number of microseconds per system tick via `unsigned int usPerTick(void);`

How can I create a fixed-width time stamp string in C? I can be flexible in this format, but would like to support a maximum of 100 minutes and keep millisecond resolution. One example format would be `"99:59:999"` meaning it has been 99 mins and 59.999 seconds since cold start.

`printf` allows me to write decimals (minute, second, ms) with a minimum width, but not a maximum width. I am looking for simple solutions.

Comment: This is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130747

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to print a fixed width, leading zeroes fractional part for the microseconds.  Since there are 6 digits in microseconds, you want,

```
sprintf(timestamp,"%d:%02d.%06d",ticks/60,ticks%60,mseconds);
```

And add struct/pointer flavor to taste...

Comment: I went with `sprintf(timestamp, "%02d:%02d.%03d", minutes, seconds, milliseconds);`. For a fixed width string the minutes also needed a leading zero. I also added checks to ensure minutes, seconds, and milliseconds were not longer than 2,2, and 3 digits respectively to ensure that the timestamp buffer did not get overrun.

Comment: Excellent! I have used a similar pattern for logging high resolution timing on embedded systems, et al.